# Why can't I instantiate this class when using the classname and namespace?

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces

I have the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Assessment;
class Database {

        private $server;
        private $username;
        private $password;
        private $database;

        public $conn;

        public function __construct()
        {           
            $this->server = "localhost";
            $this->username = "root";
            $this->password = "Museum2013";
            $this->database = "rest_test";

            $this->conn = mysqli_connect("$this->server","$this->username","$this->password","$this->database");

            if(!$this->conn)
            {
                echo "Database connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error();;
            } 
        }
}

$database = new Assessment\Database;

?>
```

When I run the code with the namespace, it does not work. But when I remove the namespace from top and in object then the code works fine. I also want to use the namespace in child class but I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: replace `$database = new Assessment\Database;` with `$database = use Assessment\Database;`

Comment: It is not error but the page does not load and it says and return HTTP error 500.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$database = new Assessment\Database;
```

Since the class name exists in a file with declared namespace (your namespace declaration at the top), class names are *relative* to the namespace of the file (unless you declare them with the fully qualified class name).

That statement was the equivalent of trying to instanstiate `Assessment\Assessment\Database`.

So you can simply do:

```
$database = new Database();
```

And it will work, since it would be the equivalent of instantiating `Assessment\Database`.

If you want to keep the fully qualified class name, just prepend a `\` to make de path start from the root namespace:

```
$database = new \Assessment\Database();
```